# Google Analytics: 'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}], get the result 658, but the GA Cpanel Users is 621, why?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics

'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}], get the result 658, but the GA Cpanel Users is 621;

'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:sessionCount'}], get the result 584, but the GA Cpanel Sessions is 676;
'metrics': [ {'expression': 'ga:sessionsPerUser'}], get the result 0.89, but the GA Cpanel sessionsPerUser is 1.09;
'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageviewsPerSession'}], get the result 2.44, but the GA Cpanel pageviewsPerSession is 2.11;
'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:bounceRate'}], get the result 45.07%, but the GA Cpanel bounceRate is 46.15%

the API data is not equal to the GA Cpanel data, why??? Have any solutions for the problem??? Thank you.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to have the same results as is in the report on the website you need to include all of the dimensions and metrics in that report in your request or the analytics wont be the same and your numbers will be diffrent.

Comment: @DaImTo the third picture is the demo, I don't know which dimensions or metrics haven't been included, please give some suggestion, my dear friend

Comment: I am not sure what view you are looking at its in chinese but every number is probably a metric you need every single one of those in your request you appear to only be making a request on users and hour over date.  Thats not the same as the report in your picture it has a lot more data.

Comment: @DaImTo Because there is a lot of problem data, I thought that if a solution can be found for one problem data, the cause of other problem data may be similar, and then solved one by one, So I have been always confused the "ga:users" return 658, but GA is 621

Comment: This is a multi dimensional database.  You cant compare data from one report to another report.   If you want to see x y and z then you need to request x y and z in both reports or the numbers will not be the same

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare google analytics data the requests made that result in the data must be the same.  They must be the same dates, dimensions, metrics, filters .. everything must be the same.

A custom report with only hours and users

[image]

The same reuqest using the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A78110423&start-date=2019-12-01&end-date=2019-12-01&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3Ahour
```

[image]

Google analytics is a multi dimensional database it is not a relational database you cant treat it as such.  Requests must be the same. So whatever report you are looking at look closely find all of the dimensions and metrics its using as well as any filters and run your request against the api with that.